# Excel: I need a conditional formatting formula to check a continuously increasing number of sheets for a value

Tags: excel, vlookup, conditional-formatting

=NOT(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A2,'Week of 06-18-18'!$P:$P,1,FALSE)))

I have used this formula to check one sheet. (entered in the conditional formatting box)

But I need it to check all sheets as I add more. I will be adding one sheet per week from now on. The values it needs to check will always show up in column P.

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to do more broadly? For example: I need to check to see if any of the sheets have matching values in a certain column.

I don't think there's a way to do this efficiently in a conditional formatting formula.

Comment: Are you trying to have the conditional format formula's date update every week? I think you'll have to use VBA for that.

Comment: The first sheet in the workbook has all of the locations listed.

Each week cycle counts are done on several locations, which are uploaded into their own sheet. I want the first sheet to highlight which locations have already been counted, adding the ones that were counted each week. The formula I posted will do it for one sheet at a time, but I would like to make it so that it encompasses all current and future sheets.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** for Excel versions before 2013:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'Week of "&TEXT(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&520-SUMPRODUCT(--ISERROR(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'Week of "&TEXT(ROW(INDIRECT("1:520"))*7+43262,"mm-dd-yy")&"'!A1"),)))))*7+43262,"mm-dd-yy")&"'!P:P"),A2))>0
```

As written, this will work for 520 "Week of" worksheets. If you need more (which I can't imagine) or less, change the two instances of "520" to however many "Week of" worksheets you need. Smaller values speed the formula up (by more than I expected).

Also, both formulas require that the dates in the "Week of" worksheets are exactly 7 days apart from each other.

---

**Original Answer:**

This should do it (although it will start to get really slow after several weeks). You can speed it up by changing "P:P" to a string representing a smaller range (e.g., "P1:P10000").

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'Week of "&TEXT(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&SHEETS()-SHEET('Week of 06-18-18'!A1)+1))*7+43262,"mm-dd-yy")&"'!P:P"),A2))>0
```

Screen shots of it in action:

I set up all "Week of" sheets identically:
[image]

If I put the formula above (shown in `B1`) into the conditional formatting formula for `A1`, the formatting shows when I set `A2` to "A", "B", or "C". I entered the same formula into `B2`, and it shows `TRUE`:

[image]

But if I change `A2` to "D", the conditional formatting does not show, and `B2` returns `FALSE`:
[image]

If I add the fourth "Week of" sheet and set it up as shown below, then the formula returns `TRUE` and the conditional formatting is displayed with "D" in `A2`.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I entered this into the rule into the "Format values where this formula is true:" box, and it does not work. Is that where you meant for me to put it?

Comment: I had it pointing to A1 instead of A2. It's updated. Try it again.

Comment: @MicahMaddox. I added some screenshots of it working. Try putting `=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'Week of "&TEXT(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&SHEETS()-SHEET('Week of 06-18-18'!A1)+1))*7+43262,"mm-dd-yy")&"'!P:P"),A2))` into a cell and set A2 to a value that is in one of the "Week of" sheets. What does it return?

Comment: I have changed the conditional formatting to the formula you provided, and put the formula in cell B2. B2 returns as "#NAME?" and the formatting does not change.

Comment: Ok. Let's figure out what's going on. First, send me the list of your sheet names (left to right). Second, enter the formula `=SHEET()` into each sheet and check that the result goes in ascending order for each sheet left to right.

Comment: U232 Rolling total, U232 Locations, Week of 06-18-18, Week of 06-25-18

When I enter "=Sheet()" It returns  "#NAME?"

Comment: What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: I am using 2010

Comment: `SHEET()` and `SHEETS()` only work for 2013 and later. I'll look for a work-around.

Comment: I found a work-around. It has the added benefit of not requiring the "Week of" worksheets to be the last (in terms of order created) sheets in the workbook.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much for your help!